# Lipo battery protection circuit. Is this a good approach?

Tags: mosfet, lipo

[image][image]

I want to build a circuit for a quadcopter where MOSFETs are connected to the primary and secondary battery. When the voltage falls below certain value in the primary battery the voltage monitor triggers the P channel MOSFET and cut the supply from primary and simultaneously the N channel MOSFET connected to the secondary battery turns ON and supplies the power. Batteries are rated 22 V Max current is 250 A.

Comment: Why a PMOS for one and an NMOS for the other battery ? That makes no sense to me but perhaps you have a good reason, if so share it.

Comment: The idea was to use one of the 1-8s voltage monitors for lipos with buzzer that indicates whether a cell has discharged below the predefined voltage. Discard the buzzer and connect the MOSFETs to it, so that when the output of the tester is high the PMOS is turned off and NMOS is turned on.

Comment: Using batteries sequentially makes no sense.

Comment: The primary battery is the main supply, in order to protect the battery from overdischarge, as soon as one of the cell voltage is low the power supply should terminate and switch to the secondary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you insist on using the batteries separately I would recommend something similar to this, although it can also be done with N-FETs on the low side

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFvsJp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The schematic below should work for inverting the output signal for control of the primary pack.  The actual values for components should be evaluated based on actual circuit needs(Gate voltages on specific MOSFETs, filtering needs, etc.)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEhFXA.png)</sup>

Comment: When the tester voltage is high, wont both the PMOS turn off?

Comment: What are you intending to use as a tester?  I would recommend two outputs with one being inverted, how you choose to do this is up to you.  If you are using a hardware circuit to test the voltage the inverted output can be generated with a simple FET inverter, if you are using a micro-controller or similar you can simply use two output pins.

Comment: The idea was to use one of the 1-8s voltage monitors for lipos with buzzer that indicates whether a cell has discharged below the predefined voltage. Discard the buzzer and connect the MOSFETs to it, so that when the output of the tester is high the PMOS is turned off and NMOS is turned on

Comment: I would think that the output to the buzzer is a PWM signal, which is definitely not what you want to connect to the MOSFETs, thats an easy way to burn them up.  Second, the output most likely wont be equal to the primary pack voltage, which would be necessary to turn the P-FET off.  I would recommend using an RC filter to ensure there is no frequency component on the output and then control the MOSFETs from the output with level shifting circuits, which are easy to find on google.

Comment: Could you please explain more about the PMOS. The primary battery input is 22V about 250 A of max current. What kind of PMOS should I select?

Comment: Do the motors actually draw close to the 250A? If you need something to switch that kind of power you should definitely use NMOS instead.  For that amount of power you may want more than one FET per line. The main thing you want to look for is a low Rdson, which will result in the lowest loss of power, and you want to be sure that the FETs are rated for a higher voltage and current rating.  Where I work we typically try to design for double the rating, which in this case we would use 40V FETs with a total capability per battery pack of 500A.

Comment: Yes, nmos would work for the secondary battery which should turn on when the voltage tester outputs to its gate. But the primary should turn off at that time and if I use a nmos for the primary as well I am not sure how to keep the mosfet conducting when there is no voltage at its gate during normal operation

Comment: I have edited my answer to include a schematic of a sample circuit.  when the output of the tester is low the first pack will be conducting and the second will not. When the output is high, the opposite is true.

Comment: The circuit works fine. But i had to remove one of the resistors. I have attached the circuit. Also there is a problem with case 3 in the circuit mentioned below. Case1: When the voltage sense output is low Battery 1 is supplying. Case 2: when the voltage sense output is high battery 2 is supplying. Case 3: When the voltage sense is low again battery 1 is not conducting unless I connect the gate of MOSFET 1 to ground for a brief moment. I tried connecting a pull down resistor between the gate and ground but in this case battery 1 is always connected regardless of the sense output.

Comment: Why did you need to remove the resistor?  Most MOSFETs are rated for less than 20V on the gate, which was the original intention of the voltage divider.  For case 3, I would recommend an additional resistor from the gate of MOSFET 1 to the negative of pack one, as there may be some weird latching going on between the packs.

Comment: I tested the circuit with 3.7V batteries on a bread board and it worked. Now I implemented the circuit with 22V LiPo batteries and ran into couple of problems. 1: When I connect only the second battery without no input to the gate of M3, the LED still glows. 2) The sense output is 5V which I think is not sufficient to cut off the first battery. When the sense output is given to the circuit the LED still glows but with less intensity.